# Loading Artists from Android MediaStore along with Artwork

Tags: android, mediastore

I am aware that media artwork is stored under albums and to get them you need to have the album id to access it. I have been able to get the images for tracks and albums using the album id.

However for artists table doesn't have the album id field. Other apps such as Play Music and Poweramp are somehow able to get the track artwork and add them to the respective artists.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is to get all albums for an artist and then use the rnd function to return an albumid:

```
         String artist_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID));

    Cursor crs = album.getArtistsAlbumcursor(mContext, artist_id);
    if(crs!=null && crs.moveToFirst()) {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int rnd = rn.nextInt( crs.getCount());
        crs.moveToPosition(rnd);
        album_id = crs.getLong(crs.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        crs.close();
    }
```

where getArtistsAlbumcursor is:

```
      public Cursor getArtistsAlbumcursor(Context context, String artistId) {

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String album_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;
    final String artistid = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID;
    final String[] columns = { _id,  album_id, artistid };
    String where =  artistid +" =?";
    String[] aId = {artistId};
    return cr.query(uri, columns, where, aId, null);
}
```

Once you have an albumid you can get your albumart using your original method.

Or

if you want to get the albumart from the mp3 track itself, you will need to implement a libary such as jaudiotagger or org.blinkenlights.jid3.v2.

Life gets a little more complicated but below how to get albumart from the mp3 tag using the JID3 library:

```
            try {
        bmp = getmp3AlbumArt(sourceFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where getmp3Albumart is:

```
        public Bitmap getmp3AlbumArt(File SourceFile) throws Exception {
    Bitmap bmp = null;
           arrayByte = null;
    APICID3V2Frame frames[];
    MediaFile MediaFile = new MP3File(SourceFile);
    try {
        Object obj = null;
        obj = MediaFile.getID3V2Tag();
        if (obj != null) {
            tagImage = (org.blinkenlights.jid3.v2.ID3V2_3_0Tag) obj;
            if ((tagImage != null) && (arrayByte == null) && (tagImage.getAPICFrames() != null) && (tagImage.getAPICFrames().length > 0)) {
                frames = tagImage.getAPICFrames();
                for (int i = 0; i < tagImage.getAPICFrames().length; i++) {
                    if (frames[i] != null) {
                        arrayByte = frames[i].getPictureData();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ID3Exception | OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (arrayByte != null) {
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arrayByte, 0, arrayByte.length);
        } catch (Exception|OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```